# ISTIO policy issue

Tags: prometheus, istio

I have a K8s Prometheus service which uses two distinct ports to map to the same targetPort and I would like to apply an authentication policy to only one port. The idea is to be able to expose the service outside the mesh with jwt authentication (using gateway/virtual service) as well as to have an internal version without authentication (I need it as there is a client inside the mesh that does not support jwt authentication).

Although my policy defines the target as the first port, the policy affects both ports. Below are some more details

1. Service

   > prometheus-service                        ClusterIP      10.233.31.30 
   >           9095/TCP,9090/TCP   22d

As can be seen, there are two ports 9095 and 9090 which are named respectively http-port1 and http-port-2

2. Policy

I created a policy below which defines the target for the first port only, http-port1.

```
Name:         prometheus-auth-policy
Namespace:    powerone-ns
API Version:  authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Policy
Spec:
  Origins:
    Jwt:
      Issuer:    testing@secure.istio.io
      Jwks Uri:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.3/security/tools/jwt/samples/jwks.json
  Peers:
    Mtls:
  Principal Binding:  USE_ORIGIN
  Targets:
    Name:  prometheus-service
    Ports:
      Name:  http-port1
```

Using istioctl command, I can see that the policies seem to be applied ok. For instance, running the command **./istioctl authn tls-check prometheus-bb6f66586-ffwml -n powerone-ns** I can see that my policy is only applied to the first service and that the second is only using the default one.

```
               HOST:PORT                                                            STATUS       SERVER        CLIENT                 AUTHN POLICY                             DESTINATION RULE
prometheus-service01.prometheus-service.svc.cluster.local:9090                       OK           mTLS          mTLS       prometheus-auth-policy/prometheus-service     default/prometheus-service
prometheus-service02.prometheus-service.svc.cluster.local:9095                       OK           HTTP/mTLS     mTLS       default/                                      default/pprometheus-service
```

When I query the service on both port without informing any token, I am able to connect fine which is wrong as the policy should require a JWT token. As soon as I delete the second port, the query fails with the expected 401 ERROR (Origin authentication failed.) as I am not informing any token. Therefore, it seems that ISTIO is not respecting the target information on my policy.

I also tried a variation of the approach. I mean, instead of having one service with two distinct ports, I created two different services (one for each port) but the same issue happens.

From my point of view, it looks like a bug.

Comment: What is your istio version? What platform/infastructure You use?

Comment: @jt97 it is istio 1.1.9 and I am running on top of kubernetes v1.14.3.

Comment: I have 2 ideas in my mind, first, You should update your istio, You use version 1.1.9 when in policy You use jwks from release 1.3, something bad might happen here. Second idea is to look at the Targets, i guess it should be `Name: http-port1` and the port You wanna use. More about authn-policy [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/)

Comment: @jt97 I tried using both name and port. My understanding is that the code is using the targetPort instead of the port to attach the policy. According to the document, it should use the port which is unique in my case but I guess it is not using it. I will try later to upgrade istio version but for now I am testing a different approach to address it

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#policy-storage-scope) and [this](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#target-selectors). I think your prometheus pods might be in istio-system namespace, when policy is in powerone-ns namespace and then `Policies in the namespace-scope storage can only affect services in the same namespace`.

Comment: @jt97 In fact I am not using Prometheus available on ISTIO namespace, I deployed my own namespace with Prometheus on that.

Comment: Did you enable sidecar injection to your new namespace? Did you disable mutual TLS? You have only 1 or more auth policies? Good to know that `For each service, Istio applies the narrowest matching policy. The order is: service-specific > namespace-wide > mesh-wide. If more than one service-specific policy matches a service, Istio selects one of them at random. Operators must avoid such conflicts when configuring their policies`.